# XMLParserについて

Tags: swift3

swift3によるXMLParserについて。

以下のcodeで実行した場合data=nilとなってしまって困ってます。

WebAPIを利用して現在地に対して住所を取得するためのものです。

urlはコンソール画面に出力された文字列をコピペでブラウザに打ち込むとXMLデータはしっかり表示されます。

他のサイト等でこの方法が記述されていたので真似てみたのですがうまくいきません・・・

結果は『　else{ print("data = nil") 』　が実行されます。。。

```
func parse(latitude:String,longtude:String){
    let url = URL(string:"geoapi.heartrails.com/api/xml?method=searchByGeoLocation&x=\(longtude)&y=\(latitude)")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!,completionHandler:{data,response,erorr in do{
        if data != nil {
            let parser = XMLParser(data:data!)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()

            if parser.parserError != nil{
                print("error")
            }
        } else {print("data = nil")}
    }
})
task.resume()
}
```

ですお願いします。

Comment: **data = nil** と出力されるなら`data != nil`が成立していないわけですから、`XMLParser`の問題ではなく、それ以前の問題ですね。`URL`の作り方が明らかに間違っているのですが、「urlはコンソール画面に出力された文字列」とあるのにコード中には`url`を出力するようなコードが見当たらないので、一体何を確かめられたのかがわかりません。そもそもブラウザのURL入力欄は"www."を付け足すなど、不完全なURLを自動的に補完してしまうことがあるので、URLが正しく作成されているかを確認するのには向いていません。`URLSession`の`data`が`nil`になってしまう場合、普通なら`error`にその原因となる情報が入っていますから、`print("data = nil")`を`print("data = nil, error=\(error)")`と変更してみて、その出力を質問中に追加していただけませんか。「コンソール画面に出力された文字列」の内容もお示しください。

Comment: OOPerさん速い回答ありがとうございました。ご指摘のようにhttp://を補完してくれてたみたいでした・・・お恥ずかしい限りです><　上記の文字列付け足したら普通に動きましたありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決できたのであれば何よりです。できれば時間をとってご自身で回答を書いてみてください。